# Compiler displaying uninitialized temp variable

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Working on a function that receives an array, its size (n), and returns an array containing any missing integers/updates the size parameter...the array I'm using is {3, 1, 3, 0, 6, 4}, n = 6. I created a temp array to increment at various indices....hence, any indices = 0 would then be equivalent to the missing variables. I keep getting a "using uninitialized memory 'temp'" warning and nothing populates to screen.....any assistance you can offer would be greatly appreciated....

```
int* findMissing(int arr[], int n, int& resArrSize) {

    int* temp = new int[n + 1];
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
        temp[arr[i]]++;
    }
    int* missingInts = new int[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if (temp[i] == 0) {
            missingInts[count] = temp[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    delete[] temp;
    resArrSize = count;
    return missingInts;
}
```

Comment: Here you increment:  `temp[arr[i]]++;`  but the values in the array have not been initialised. The declaration `int* temp = new int[n + 1];` does not set the values in the array to 0.

Comment: This is a good reason to use `std::vector<int>` to store your `temp`, it would have correctly initialized the members to zero.

Answer (score 1):

`int* temp = new int[n + 1];`
whith no  Initialize, maybe you can use memset or other in

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `int* temp = new int[n + 1];` creates a new array but does not initialize the contents of that array.

When `temp[arr[i]]++;` is executed, you're incrementing the value of the uninitialized `arr[i]`, which is what's causing the compiler warning.